# Why does UIButton need a constraint in order to appear in UIStackView

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, uistackview

Given the following Playground code, I'd expect my two buttons to fill up the entire StackView.

```
import UIKit

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = .purple

let anotherButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
anotherButton.setTitle("Another Button", for: .normal)
anotherButton.backgroundColor = .orange

var stackView: UIStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300, height: 300))
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.spacing = 10.0
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.alignment = .fill

stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(anotherButton)
stackView
```

But none of them shows up! However, if I add a width constraint of 1px to either of the buttons, both buttons are laid out as expected.

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)
```

I'm puzzled! Why does this single constraint make a difference? Should I do something else rather than adding a "dummy constraint", to enforce the buttons to be laid out correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug in playgrounds , but This worked with me in app without any **widthAnchor** constraints

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .purple



    let anotherButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    anotherButton.setTitle("Another Button", for: .normal)
    anotherButton.backgroundColor = .orange

    var stackView: UIStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 100.0, width: 300, height: 300))
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 10.0
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(anotherButton)

    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
}
```

[image]

Comment: All right - thank you for your reply/test! I just wanted to quickly verify how buttons behave within a StackView, and thought PlayGround would be the fastest way of achieving this. But then again, not so much if I can't rely on how PlayGround renders my code!